# Как сравнивать значение в методе?

Tags: java

Не понятно каким образом сравнивать значение зарплаты в методе.

> У вас есть два работника, вам нужно узнать, кто получает больше денег и на сколько. Для этого создайте 2 объекта класса Salary, с экземпляром, который содержит зарплату работника. Далее передайте объект, как аргумент, метода для сравнения

Код Main:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salary first = new Salary();
        Salary second = new Salary();
        first.Employee("Сергей", 500);
        second.Employee("Артём", 700);
    }
}
```

Код Salary:

```java
public class Salary {
    public void Employee(String name, int salary) {
        System.out.println("Имя: " + name + " Зарплата: " + salary);
    }

    public void CompareSalary(Salary _employee) {
        _employee.Employee("Name", 400); ???
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас есть метод `CompareSalary` и у вас есть есть поле `private int salary` - какие проблемы?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что `return this.salary - _employee.salary;` - результат будет 0 если равны, отрицательный если зарплата this меньше и положительный если зарплата this больше. Чем-то напоминает перегрузку операторов в C++, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А может проще попробовать?

```
public class Salary {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Salary(String name, int salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void CompareSalary(Salary employee){
        String msg = name + " получает столько же сколько и " + employee.getName();
       if (salary > employee.getSalary()) {
           msg = name + " получает больше чем " + employee.getName() + " на " + (salary - employee.getSalary());
       } else if (salary < employee.getSalary()) {
           msg = name + " получает меньше чем " + employee.getName() + " на " + (employee.getSalary() - salary);
       }

        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Salary{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }
}
```

вместо метода Employee можно просто переопределить метод toString.
Валидация значений на вашей совести.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Salary first = new Salary("Сергей", 700);
    Salary second= new Salary("Артём", 800);

    first.CompareSalary(second);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Как-то всё странно у вас. Просто делаете конструктор и метод для сравнения, куда передается параметр - второй объект для сравнения. В языке такое уже есть в интерфейсе `Comparable`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salary first = new Salary("Сергей", 500);
        Salary second = new Salary("Артём", 700);
        if(first.compareTo(second) > 0){
            System.out.println("Больше получает " + first.getName());
        } else if(first.compareTo(second) < 0){
            System.out.println("Больше получает " + second.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Оба получают одинаково");
        }

    }
}

public class Salary implements Comparable<Salary> {

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Salary(String name, int salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void print(String name, int salary){
        System.out.println("Имя: " + name + " Зарплата: " + salary);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Salary o) {
        return Integer.compare(salary, o.getSalary());
    }
}
```